# Overflow error for encryption

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an overflow error in the following code:

```
    Public Shared Function AESFileEncrypt(inputFilename As String, outputFilename As String) As Boolean

    'Create SymmetricAlgorithm object and specify the Key and IV.
    Dim AES As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged

    AES.Key = objKeys.aesKey
    AES.IV = objKeys.aesIV

    'Create an ICryptoTransform (Encryptor) object.
    Dim Encryptor As ICryptoTransform

    Encryptor = AES.CreateEncryptor

    'Read the unencrypted file.
    Dim InputFileStream As FileStream
    InputFileStream = New FileStream(inputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim InputFileData(CType(InputFileStream.Length, Integer)) As Byte
    InputFileStream.Read(InputFileData, 0, CType(InputFileStream.Length, Integer))

    Dim OutputFileStream As FileStream
    OutputFileStream = New FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    'Create a CryptoStream object using the Stream and ICryptoTransform objects.
    Dim EncryptCryptoStream As CryptoStream
    EncryptCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(OutputFileStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    EncryptCryptoStream.Write(InputFileData, 0, InputFileData.Length)
    EncryptCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    'Clear any sensitive data from the cyptographic object.
    AES.Clear()

    'Close stream objects.
    EncryptCryptoStream.Close()
    InputFileStream.Close()
    OutputFileStream.Close()

    Return True

    'Catch ex As Exception
    'Debug.Print("AESFileEncrypt", ex.Message)
    'Return False
    'End Try

End Function
```

The error is at this line:

```
        Dim InputFileData(CType(InputFileStream.Length, Integer)) As Byte
```

This happens on large files. I know it is because the byte array cannot be that large. Can I please have some help to modify this code to get it working?

Thanks

*EDIT*

This is my current work on this function:

```
    Public Function AESFileEncrypt(inputFilename As String, outputFilename As String, Password As String, Salt As String) As Boolean

    Dim AES As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged

    Dim HashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1" 'Can be SHA1 or MD5
    Dim PasswordIterations As String = 2
    Dim InitialVector As String = "WinStorePassword" 'This should be a string of 16 ASCII characters.
    Dim KeySize As Integer = 256 'Can be 128, 192, or 256.

    Dim InitialVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector)
    Dim SaltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt)
    Dim DerivedPassword As PasswordDeriveBytes = New PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations)
    Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8)

    Dim Encryptor As ICryptoTransform

    Encryptor = AES.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes)

    Dim InputFileStream As FileStream
    InputFileStream = New FileStream(inputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim OutputFileStream As FileStream
    OutputFileStream = New FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Dim EncryptCryptoStream As CryptoStream
    EncryptCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(OutputFileStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    Const BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 4096
    Dim buffer(BUFFER_SIZE - 1) As Byte
    Dim Position As Long

    Do

        If (Position + BUFFER_SIZE) > InputFileStream.Length Then
            InputFileStream.Read(buffer, Position, InputFileStream.Length - Position)
            EncryptCryptoStream.Write(buffer, Position, BUFFER_SIZE)
            Exit Do
        Else
            InputFileStream.Read(buffer, Position, BUFFER_SIZE)
            EncryptCryptoStream.Write(buffer, Position, BUFFER_SIZE)
        End If

        Position += BUFFER_SIZE

    Loop

    EncryptCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    AES.Clear()

    EncryptCryptoStream.Close()
    InputFileStream.Close()
    OutputFileStream.Close()

    Return True

End Function
```

Is this correct? I did a test an a small file, and the output was a lot larger than i expected?

Comment: Why are you reading the whole file in memory? Use a fixed size buffer and read the file in small chunks, copying those chunks from the input to the output stream, until you reach the end of the input file.

Comment: Can you point me in the correct direction to look into this please. Maybe an example if possible. Thanks.